# Unknown word comes up automatically after changing password on a user

Tags: prompt

I am using Redhat 5.4 and when I tend to change Oracle user password this comes up right after hitting Enter:

```
passwd oracle
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@server~]# H0!gh%12
-bash: H0!gh%12: command not found
```

** it is not accidental type of the password.**

Why "H0!gh%12" comes up and how I can get rid of it?!

Comment: What is the command you're using to change the password?

Comment: it loks to me like an accidental paste of the new password

Comment: Is this consistently reproducible?

Comment: are you using debian as linux flavour and do you have installed TMUX?

Comment: For Linux: I am using Redhat 5.4 and assume we are not using TMUX
I am fairly new to linux, so please bare with me as I am trying my best!

Comment: Do you manually type in the password, then?

Comment: @Sparhawk Manually type or Copy and paste is not the case. this word comes up after I change any user 's passwrod! –

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory, but it looks like someone might have aliased the `passwd` command (poorly, in this case) on your machine, possibly to avoid having to enter the password in twice. The correct sequence for a password exchange should be:

```
[17:09:50][root@test1][/root]# passwd tester1
Changing password for user tester1.            ## Notice that your exchange
New password:                                  ## is missing these lines
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[17:10:40][root@test1][/root]#
```

If an alias is "eating" the first two lines of the exchange in order to save your input and spit it back out to the `passwd` command, you might be able to find it by using the `alias` or `set` commands to determine if there are system-wide aliases. Alternatively, you could check and see if someone has replaced the `passwd` command with a shell script by using the `file` command.

```
[17:19:17][root@test1][/root]# file $(which passwd)
/usr/bin/passwd: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

If it's not a setuid ELF executable - either 32- or 64-bit - then shenanigans have been pulled.

Good luck.